# Can I retrieve the latest available offset for a Kafka partition without retrieving all the messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Looking at the latest (v0.10) Kafka Consumer [documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html):

"The **position** of the consumer gives the offset of the next record that will be given out. It will be one larger than the highest offset the consumer has seen in that partition. It automatically advances every time the consumer receives data calls *poll(long)* and receives messages."

Is there a way to query for the largest offset available for the partition on the server side, **without** retrieving all the messages?

The logic I am trying to implement is as follows:

1. query every second for the amount (A) of pending messages in a topic
2. if A > threshold, wake up a processor that would go ahead retrieving all the messages, and processing them
3. otherwise do nothing (sleep 1)

The motivation is that I need to do some batch processing, but I want the processor to wake up only when there is enough data (and I don't want to retrieve all the data twice).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `Consumer.seekToEnd()` method, run `Consumer.poll(0)` to make that take effect but return immediately, then `Consumer.position()` to find the positions for all subscribed (or assigned) topic partitions. These will be the current final offsets for all partitions. This will also start fetching some data from the brokers for those offsets, but any returned data will be ignored if you subsequently seek back to a different position.

Currently the alternative, as mentioned by serejja, is to use the old simple consumer, although the process is quite a bit more complicated as you need to manually find the leader for each partition.

Comment: Thanks. I wonder whether I can avoid reading all the data twice (in the scenario I described above). For example, can I reduce max.partition.fetch.bytes to a very small value in order to eliminate the 'side effect' of *poll(0)* retrieving the actual data?

Comment: You don't need to call poll().  seekToEnd() is an asynchronous call that you can force to completion with either poll() or position().  Using seek...() and position() does not read any messages, just some small amount of metadata

Comment: @ChrisGerken Not sure that's reliable if you are working with consumer groups and don't have an assignment yet (I'd have to dig into the code more carefully, but it looks like it'll throw an `IllegalArgumentException`). For manually assigned topics/topic partitions it seems that will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, I don't see how this is possible with 0.10 consumer.

However, this is doable if you have any lower level Kafka client (sorry but I'm not sure if one exists for JVM, but there are plenty of them for other languages).

So if you have some time and inspiration to implement this, here's the way to go - every `FetchResponse` (which is the response for each "give me messages" request) contains a field called `HighwaterMarkOffset`, which essentially is an offset at the end of partition (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/A+Guide+To+The+Kafka+Protocol#AGuideToTheKafkaProtocol-FetchResponse). The trick here is to send a `FetchRequest` that will immediately return (e.g. won't block waiting) nothing but HighwaterMarkOffset.

To do so your `FetchRequest` should have:

1. `MaxWaitTime` set to `0`, which would mean "return immediately if cannot fetch at least MinBytes bytes".
2. `MinBytes` set to `0`, which means "I'm OK if you return me an empty response".
3. `FetchOffset` doesn't matter in this case, and if I'm not wrong it might even be an invalid offset, but probably better to be a valid one.
4. `MaxBytes` set to `0`, which means "give me no more than 0 bytes of data", e.g. nothing.

This way this request will return immediately with no data, but still with the highwatermark offset set to a proper value. Once you have the highwatermark offset, you can compare it to your current offset and figure out how much behind you are.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, @serejja ! This certainly gives a direction to explore this further.. Any idea how can I use ideas/code from the internal [Fetcher class](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/Fetcher.java) to achieve this? The listOffset or the inner sendListOffsetRequest methods look promising..

Comment: @AlexGlikson We face a problem which is similar with yours. We use reflection to call the internal listOffset with latest timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method `public OffsetAndMetadata committed(TopicPartition partition)` from the API below to get the last committed offset

https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html